# Visual studio 2013 platform toolset v120 performance is slower then when set to v100

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Lately we switched  from visual studio 2010 to visual studio 2013, we running a mathematical algorithm in   c++  , after some measurements it seems that when we **choosing platform toolset = v100**(in visual 2013 ) the running time is 7-15%(which was total surprise for us ) **faster**  then platform **toolset =v120** ,
anyone have idea what the reason for it , 
we expected that the v120 will be actuality faster and not slower ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compilers, as all software, have bugs.
This is a bug.
Report it to Microsoft.
If you're not going to bother showing us any code, what's the point in asking? Never had a newer version of software be slower than in the good ol' days?

Comment: Unless someone just happens to know, this Q would be much better with sample code and compiler options.

Comment: Compare the assembler code.

Comment: unfortunately i can not show the code ,but i added some pictures , if you need more pictures ,just tell the info you need

Comment: Play around with the compiler option -arch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd(v=vs.100).aspx and see if it makes any difference

Comment: @HansPassant I think he was refering to the performance of the generated program and not of VS itself